three.js renderer make white crack line, antialias + logarithmicDepthBuffer option
Three.js renderer make white crack line, antialias + logarithmicDepthBuffer option like image below.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I checked the glb model with gltf-viewer(https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)
But there, the model looks great without white noise.
enter image description here
This is my three.js WebGL renderer option:
I add logarithmicDepthBuffer because I wanted to prevent from the error when zoomming out, the model's graphic part like logo text is cracking.
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
canvas: canvas,
antialias: true,
logarithmicDepthBuffer: true
});
I noticed that if i remove antialias the white cracks are gone.
And if i remove logarithmicDepthBuffer instead, the white cracks are also gone.But detail parts of the model cracks in render view when zooming out.
Help me!
How can i make a good render like  gltf-viewer(https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)?

I suggest you fix your very small images and make it clear what the problem is.
